# jquery find and replace accents to html code

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, replace, non-ascii-characters

I'm using PHP, jQuery and mySQL to build an admin site to my webpage.
In one of parts of this admin section, I use a `<textarea>` element to write several lines.
I'm Spanish and I use á é í ó ú and ñ letters.

I'm looking for any script that replace á to &aacute;

Also I'm still having problems to send `<textarea>` content to mySQL.

```
<form action="this_file.php" method="POST">
    <textarea class="inputcat" type="text" cols="40" rows="5" name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="upload text" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
//allow sessions to be passed so we can see if the user is logged in
session_start();
//connect to the database so we can check, edit, or insert data to our users table
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('dbname', $con) or die(mysql_error());
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        //insert the row into the database
        $contenido = $_POST['content'];
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO table1 (`ct`) VALUE('" .$contenido. "')";//edited sytanx
        $result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

The error is:

```
Unknown column 'Ã¬mg' in 'field list'
fixed error.
```

**last thing is to replace áéíóú and ñ letter when user request mysql to read content from a table. áéíóú are in this table and i wanna to replace in real time when user request that content**

Comment: Is your database in utf-8 charset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

php

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['normalizeChars'] = array(
'Á'=>'&Aacute;', 'É'=>'&Eacute;', 'Í'=>'&Iacute;', 'Ó'=>'&Oacute;', 'Ú'=>'&Uacute;', 'Ñ'=>'&Ntilde', 'á'=>'&aacute;', 'é'=>'&eacute;', 'í'=>'&iacute;', 'ó'=>'&oacute;', 'ú'=>'&uacute;', 'ñ'=>'&ntilde');

function makeit($toChange){
return strtr($toChange, $GLOBALS['normalizeChars']);
}

//call makeit function before you read $row content with special characters, I mean:

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pwd') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('dbname', $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// imagine that exist a column called content with special chars
makeit($row['content']);
echo $row['content'];
}
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove yours backticks

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO table1 ('ct') VALUE('" .$contenido. "')";
```

And ensure your database is in utf-8 charset

Comment: put a `echo $SQL;break;` before this line `$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());` ... show here what you get

Comment: show the array but it's interesting to see that send submit value ... can it be the problem???

Comment: sure is... instead that previous echo put: `echo '<pre>';var_dump($SQL);echo'</pre>';`

Comment: i've got it !!!!!! in my real html i used a column called img, but i SQL code its called ìmg. that's my error. i only need a script to replace áéíóúñ letters to &aacute;&eacute;&iacute; ... THANK YOU SO MUCH.